# Qual objetivo do baselineAligned?

Tags: android, warnings

No ato do desenvolvimento de uma aplicação, me deparei com o seguinte warning:

> Set android:baselineAligned="false" on this element for better
>   performance

Qual objetivo do `baselineAligned`? Quando devo usá-lo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319916/how-does-setting-baselinealigned-to-false-improve-performance-in-linearlayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`android:baselineAligned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#baselineAligned): Quando definida como `false`, impede o layout de alinhar as linhas de base de seus filhos.

Quando estiver usando um `LinearLayout` horizontal, os itens são alinhados pela posição da sua base de linha de texto (a primeira linha do primeiro elemento da lista – do topo ou da esquerda – é considerado a linha de referência). Isto serve para que as pessoas não fiquem olhando para cima e para baixo quando estão lendo os texto dos elementos vizinhos. Para desativar esta propriedade defina `android:baselineAligned=”false”` no layout XML.

Answer (score -3):

Segundo a documentação oficial `android:baselineAligned When set to false prevents the layout from aligning its children's baselines.`

Encontrada [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

Comment: Sua resposta seria mais útil se estivesse **traduzida para português**.